# Mysql select order by count or something

Tags: mysql, count

I have simple movie database and I wondering if is possible to order by COUNT, how many films belongs to each category?
I tried the query

`SELECT COUNT(category), movie_name FROM movies group by category` and I'm receiving 4 rows which means they are all counted.
4 Comedy

If I put the same query and group by movie_name I get (almost) correct order like
1 Comedy
2 Horror
1 Western

but I want to be ordered by number of films in each category like 
1 Comedy
1 Western
2 Horror

Can anyone help me?
Thank you,
Ivan.

I apologize, but I have asked wrong question and this is why I'm not receiving working query. Let say if I have movie names "   Inception,Saw,Star Wars" and have likes for that movies which all of them have value 1 (true) what means that I have 4 records for example: Saw 1, Star Wars 1, Star Wars 1 and Inception 1. Here is the query SELECT COUNT(like), movie_name FROM movies WHERE like=1 group by like. Like I said each like have a value 1 (which is true). Now I need order by count likes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `oder by` on the first column (returning count) using it's position as:

```
  SELECT COUNT(movie_name), category FROM movies group by category order by 1 asc;
```

You can also use the column alias in the order query as:

```
 SELECT COUNT(movie_name) as total_movies, category
 FROM movies 
 group by category 
 order by total_movies asc;
```

**EDIT:** Based on your inputs, you need to group by `movie_name` as

```
  SELECT COUNT(like), movie_name 
  FROM movies 
  WHERE like=1 
  GROUP BY movie_name 
  ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: Weird, I never knew you could refer to a column *index* in the `ORDER BY` clause.  Seems to work in Oracle as well, so I guess it's standard.

Comment: Still the same result ...4 Comedy in both casses

Comment: @user1991134: Would you mind sharing your data to understand to root cause of the issue?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Please refer `ORDER BY {col_name | expr | **position**}` in the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#id756773)

Comment: I apologize, but I have asked wrong question and this is why I'm not receiving working query. Let say if I have movie names " Inception,Saw,Star Wars" and have likes for that movies which all of them have value 1 (true) what means that I have 4 records for example: Saw 1, Star Wars 1, Star Wars 1 and Inception 1. Here is the query SELECT COUNT(like), movie_name FROM movies WHERE like=1 group by like. Like I said each like have a value 1 (which is true). Now I need order by count likes which means that Star Wars must be first or last with 2 likes. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: @user1991134 Its simple. You need to group by `movie_name`. Use the query as: `SELECT COUNT(like), movie_name FROM movies WHERE like=1 group by movie_name order by 1 desc`. This should return `Star Wars` with count as 2 as the first row. Let me know, if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yes, it works. I wish you posted your answer earlier as I also found what is working :)      SELECT move_name, SUM(like) as likes FROM movies WHERE like=1 group by movie_name order by likes  Thank you very much to all of you who replied to my question.

Comment: @user1991134 Sum and Count will result into same thing as like has the value 1.